# OOP structure for an old procedural programmer

Tags: php, database, api, oop

I come from the world of procedural programming with assembler being my first language and PL/1 and Cobol being the languages I learnt most of my (bad) habits from.

This is my first post here, so please accept my apologies if I am not doing it 100% correct.

I am rewriting our frontend and backend systems from procedural php to OOP and I don't really understand what structure to use.

In the old system, we have a number of scripts that include xxx.inc.php with the functions used and those xxx.inc.php in turn includes other xxx.inc.php such as db.inc.php, api_pj.inc.php etc

Trying to do this OOP, I create one file for each class and autoloads them, but I can't understand how to handle the common classes (database, connection to external api's, etc). When testing, I used inheritance and it works fine, but it feels very odd. I can't really see customer class being a child of database class.
Also I do not understand what needs to be defined and not. Should all variables in the classes be defined?

The example below do not work, since the database connection is not available for the Customer class. When having "class Customer extends DB" instead it all works fine, but I suppose there is a more correct way of doing this?

*Edited code below after reply from Alex Andrei*

the_example_page.php

```
// autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});

// data for testing
$customer_id = '12090';
$order_id = '31480';

// db
$db = new DB();
$db_conn = $db->db_connect();

// get customer name data and print it:
$customer = new Customer($db_conn);
$customer_data = $customer->get_customer_info($customer_id);
print $customer_data['name'];

// get order date and print it:
$order = new Order($db_conn);
$order_data = $order->get_order_info($order_id);
print $order_data['date'];
```

DB.class.php

```
class DB
{
    public function __construct() {}

    public function db_connect()
    {
        static $db_conn;

        if( !$db_conn )
        {
            $db_conn = pg_connect("dbname=database user=user password=PaSsWoRd");
        }
        return $db_conn;
    }

    public function db_exec($sql)
    {
        if( !$sql ) return;
        $db_conn = $this->db_connect();
        $result = @pg_exec($db_conn,$sql);
        if( !$result )
        {
            return;   
        }
        $ret[result] = $result;
        return $ret;
    }

    public function db_getrow(&$a)
    {
    # a bunch of stuff in real function, but here only a plain fetch_array as example       
        $ret = pg_fetch_array($a);
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Customer.class.php

```
class Customer
private $conn;
{
public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->conn=$db;
}

    public function get_customer_info($customer_id) 
    {
        return $this->conn->db_getrow($this->conn->db_exec("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerid = $customer_id;"));
    }

    public function get_all_customers($status) 
    {
        return $this->conn->db_exec("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE status = $status;");
    }
}
```

Order.class.php

```
class Order
{
private $conn;
{
public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->conn=$db;
}

    public function get_order_info($order_id) 
    {
        return $this->conn->db_getrow($this->conn->db_exec("SELECT * FROM order WHERE orderid = $order_id;"));
    }

    public function get_all_orders($status) 
    {
        return $this->conn->db_exec("SELECT * FROM order WHERE status = $status;");
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed a Customer *is not* a Database, so it shouldn't inherit it. Look into ***dependency injection***. From the consumer side that looks like `$db = new Database('foo', 'bar'); $cust = new Customer($db);`. Better yet: `$manager = new CustomerManager($db); $cust = $manager->get(42);`. Look into the *repository pattern.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE
Extended example on how to modify the DB connection class and the Order class

database class

```
class DB
{
    private $conn;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;

    public function __construct($database,$username,$password){

        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;

    }

    public function connect(){
        if( !$this->conn ){
            $this->conn = pg_connect("dbname=$this->database user=$this->user password=$this->password");
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function db_exec($sql){
        if( !$sql ) return; // add some relevant error message

        if (!$this->conn){
            $this->connect();
        }

        $result = pg_exec($this->conn,$sql);

        if( !$result ){
            return;   
        }
        $ret[result] = $result;

        return $ret;
    }

    public function db_getrow(&$a){
    # a bunch of stuff in real function, but here only a plain fetch_array as example       
        $ret = pg_fetch_array($a);
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Order class

```
class Order
{
    private $dbObj;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->dbObj=$db;
    }

    public function get_order_info($order_id) 
    {
        $result = $this->dbObj->db_exec("SELECT * FROM order WHERE orderid = $order_id;");
        return $this->dbObj->db_getrow($result);
    }

    public function get_all_orders($status) 
    {
        return $this->conn->db_exec("SELECT * FROM order WHERE status = $status;");
    }
}
```

Usage

```
$db = new DB("myDatabase","user","password");
$db->connect();

$order = new Order($db);
```

---

You don't have to `extend` everything, only what makes sense.

Just pass the db connection as a parameter to the other objects, so the queries can be executed.

Ex.

```
$customer = new Customer($db);
$order = new Order($db);
```

You should add a private variable for each class to hold the database connection, ex

```
class Customer{
    private $conn;

    // ...
}
```

and the constructor would look like this

```
public function __construct($db) {
    $this->conn = $db;
}
```

using it in the methods like so

```
public function get_order_info($order_id){
    return $this->conn->db_getrow($this->db_exec("SELECT * FROM order WHERE orderid = $order_id;"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So if I understand you correctly, I'll instigate (if that is what it is called) the database in the_example_page.php via $db =  new DB(); and send this to the other classes? But that is an object and not a connection? Or? In DB.class.php, the connection is $db_conn so I thought that would be what should be passed to the other classes. (Probably I am misunderstanding it all, but will read through it more when I am back in an hour)

Comment: Yep. Pretty much. The DB object has a method that returns a `connection`. You would pass this as an argument to tge other classes. It's "instantiate" :)

Comment: I updated the code, but get error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function db_getrow() on a non-object in classes/Customer.class.php on line 12
 
 Line 12 is: return $this->conn->db_getrow($this->conn->db_exec("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerid = $customer_id;"));

Comment: I updated my answer with some changes to your classes and usage. The changes you did had an extra `{` after the private variable definition.

Answer (score -1):

You can `extend` the other classes if they use the `database` class and then invoke them in the child constructor. Watch out for conflicting variables within the methods if you choose this approach.

If the `Customer` class extends the `Database` class then it will have access to the methods of `Database` etc

```
class Database{
    public function __construct(){
    }
    /* other methods*/
}

class Customer extends Database{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
class Order extends Database{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the downvote so damn quickly... accidentally submit the half finished post and...

Comment: It's not about the half-finished answer, it's about bad OOP practices. A Customer *is not* a Database, so shouldn't inherit it. See my comment under the question.

Comment: Secondarily, if your Customer doesn't do anything in its constructor besides calling the parent constructor, just leave it out completely, no need to write it at all.

Comment: thanks @deceze, gave me something to look into with this `dependency injection`